# Need help to change power management settings

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management

Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS is freshly installed on my Acer Swift 314-57 laptop.  The laptop wakes up for no apparent reason, which I don't really want.  There is no Intel Smart Connect setting in the Bios.  Based on what I learned from other questions, here is a list of possible culprits:

```
~$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep enabled
XHC   S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
RP13      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
TXHC      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:0d.0
TDM0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:0d.2
TRP0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.0
PWRB      S4    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0C:00
```

How can I find out what these items are?
How can I disable some of them?

Answer (score 2):

- PWRB is the power button.
- XHC is for the USB 3.0 port
- RP13 is for the PCI slot
- TXHC is for the thunderbolt controller
- TDM0 - can not find this one. edit: might be Target Display Mode. So an action on a display, like turning it on, that envokes wake up.
- TRP0 - TRAP. Can not find this one but could be software related.

Install `acpitool` The `-W {digit}` option allows disabling and enabling events. Do not mess with PWRB... if you disable it you disable the power button... it will be a lot more difficult to start your system without that button.

Comment: I appreciate the codes you translated, but am surprised that some cannot be found.  How does one find such codes?

Comment: @adr looking through the acpi software ;-) well the parts that are open source. I have not found those in the documents for acpi though :(

Comment: Is that really the *only* way to find such information?  Seems suboptimal.

Comment: Took me more than an hour to even find this.And technically I guessed words together with the letterds and search for them. PWRB was easy. But like HC: Host Controller seemed a good start. So the T I assumed Thunderbolt. That led me back to USB for XHC. The RP. I guesses the P might me PCI and I found a couple of google hits where RP0/1/2/3 is menthioned with pci controller...

Comment: Wow, amazing the thing runs at all!

Comment: I disabled XHC and RP13 and will wait to see if that solves the problem.

Comment: The changes made by the acpitool are not persistent.  :(

Comment: @adr easy to circumvent: add it to a script, make it executable and add that script to /etc/crontab or startup applications. (making it a systemd call is another option but more difficult)